# MySQL “Inner Join” query from three tables giving wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sum

I am working on a HR project where I need to call 3 tables values from a mysql database and need a custom output based on some criteria which are as below:
But I an unable to get output wht i am looking for. I am new to mysql and need your guideline to get the output as Below. Thanks in advance for your wise advise...

**Table Employee**

> EMP_ID -      EMP_NAME
>
> EID001 -     TOM
>
> EID002 -   LARRY

**Table Attendance**

> EMP_ID - EMP_NAME -    ATTENDANCE_DATE
>
> EID001 -   TOM -       20200101
>
> EID002 -   LARRY - 20200101
>
> EID001 -   TOM -       20200102
>
> EID002 -   TOM -       20200103
>
> EID002 -   TOM -   20200104

**Table Leave_Record**

> EMP_ID - EMP_NAME -    LEAVE_DATE(FROM) -  LEAVE_DATE(TO) -    DAYS -  LEAVE_TYPE
>
> EID002 -   LARRY   - 20200102  - 20200102  - 1 - CASUAL
>
> EID002 -   LARRY    - 20200103 - 20200103  - 1 - SICK
>
> EID002  - LARRY    - 20200104   - 20200104 - 1 - ANNUAL

**Looking output**

> EMP_ID -   EMP_NAME -  WORKING_DAYS -  CASUAL_LEAVE -  SICK_LEAVE -    ANNUAL_LEAVE
>
> EID001 -TOM    - 4 - 0 - 0 - 0
>
> EID002 - LARRY - 4 - 1 - 1 - 1

***My MySql query:***
`SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_Name, SUM(Attendance. ATTENDANCE_DATE!='') as WORKING_DAYS, SUM(Leave_Record.LEAVE_TYPE='CASUAL') as CASUAL, SUM(Leave_Record.LEAVE_TYPE=SICK) as SICK , SUM(Leave_Record.LEAVE_TYPE=ANNUAL) as ANNUAL  from Employee, Attendance, Leave_Record where Attendance. EMP_ID = Employee. EMP_ID AND Employee. EMP_ID = Leave_Record. EMP_ID  GROUP BY Employee. EMP_ID order by Employee. EMP_ID`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why. See the edit help re code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple matching rows in both tables, so outer aggregation would generate wrong counts. You would typically aggregate in subqueries first, then join in the outer query:

```
select 
    e.emp_id, 
    e.name, 
    coalesce(a.working_days, 0) working_days, 
    coalesce(cl.casual_leave, 0) casual_leave, 
    coalesce(cl.sick_leave, 0) sick_leave
from employee e
left join (
    select emp_id, count(*) working_days from attendance group by emp_id
) a on a.emp_id = e.emp_id
left join (
    select 
        emp_id, 
        sum(case when leave_type = 'casual' then days end) casual_leave,
        sum(case when leave_type = 'sick' then days end) sick_leave
    from leave_record
    group by emp_id
) cl on cl.emp_id = e.emp_id
```

If `leave_record(days)` is always `1`, then the second subquery can be simplified as:

```
left join (
    select 
        emp_id, 
        sum(leave_type = 'casual') casual_leave,
        sum(leave_type = 'sick') sick_leave
    from leave_record
    group by emp_id
) cl on cl.emp_id = e.emp_id
```

Comment: Hi GMB, now the result is perfectly showing....Million thanks to you...